# cron jobs won't run after boot on linux arch

Tags: archlinux, cron

I'm trying to setup a cron on boot to run yet it doesn't seems like it's working(

```
[root@alarmpi ~]# crontab -l
@reboot     /root/cgminer XXXXXXXXXX
@daily      `which pacman` --sync --refresh
[root@alarmpi ~]# uname -a
Linux alarmpi 3.6.11-14-ARCH+ #1 PREEMPT Sun Jul 21 17:39:58 CDT 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
[root@alarmpi ~]#
```

I even tried using `/etc/rc.local`, yet still unable to automatically kick off script upon boot((

please advise.

Comment: output 'ls -la /root/cgminer' - maybe you need to make it executable with 'chmod +x'

Comment: `/root/cgminer` is 755

Comment: @AwesomeUser I wasn't able to solve it via `/etc/rc.local`, so I configured `systemd` instead. Yet I still wish to know why `rc.local` didn't work.